# Caputring error message and closing log file during exception

Tags: python, error-handling

```
class Logger(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.terminal = sys.stdout

    def write(self, message):
        self.terminal.write(message)
        Output.write(message)

    def flush(self):
        # this flush method is needed for python 3 compatibility.
        # this handles the flush command by doing nothing.
        # you might want to specify some extra behavior here.
        pass

sys.stdout = Logger()
sys.stderr = Logger2()
```

I have the above chunk of code to save the output and error messages in a txt file so that I can review them after running them. This is helpful as I am running my code on a remote server and I use this for debugging.

However, whenever there is an error, the code abruptly stops and the error message is not captured in Logger2 since the output is not saved into the file( and subsequently not closed). Is there any way around this?

Comment: Isn't it normal, if you do not try/except?

Comment: Try and except would not work as the code chunk in try which outputs text will not be printed to stdout in the case of an exception. Furthermore, this does not solve the issue of the error message not printing in the log text file as the code would just stop once it hits an exception and not save that output.